# "Somehow" or "In somehow"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

So far I had never found "somehow" used with "in". Is still this the normal adverb? Could I use "somehow" alone?

> Ex: I'll fit you in somehow.

Comment: Perhaps you are confusing *somehow* with the synonym *in some way*.

Answer (score 1):

The preposition "in" goes along with *fit* and not with *somehow*. It is separated from the verb *fit* on the account of English syntax And - of course - "in somehow" by itself, would be ungrammatical.

Answer (score 0):

There's an implied noun after the preposition *in*, most likely "my schedule" or "the list of people involved" or something similar, that's elided. So, "I'll fit you in" means "I'll fit you in my schedule". (It could well be "I'll fit you in my really skinny jeans" or something completely different, but barring context telling us that, the schedule sense is the most likely).

In "I'll fit you in my schedule, somehow" the *somehow* would be modifying the verb *fit*, suggesting that while fitting you into my schedule will not be easy, I will still find a way to manage it.

"I'll fit you in somehow" hence means the same. "I'll fit you in, somehow" is probably clearer.